# Facebook authentication error while data migration

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, facebook-oauth

We are migrating data from one server to server. The requests that come to older server is being redirected to the new Ip address using htaccess. The older domain is registered with facebook. In the new domain I am getting the facebook authentication error.

> "error": {
>         "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 191    }

is there any way to do using htaccess so that it will take the older registered domain name while accessing facebook api's?

Comment: Why don’t you just set the new domain in the app settings?

Comment: The domain is not yet set. We are still in testing phase.So want to test.

Comment: for testing create new app with your account and use new AppId while in testing phase, and when you will move to live phase change domain name in your live face application then replace your testing app id with live facebook application's appid.